# Files mounted as volumes in docker-compose don't show their content in locally mounted volume

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

So I'm facing a sort of weird issue and I'm not sure the best way to even describe it. My docker compose is below.

Basically, I'm mounting `/var/www/html` to the local folder `mounted_folder`. For the most part, this works as expected and all the files in the container in that directory show up locally, but with the exception of the other files that I've mounted via docker-compose.

The files are mounting correctly and if I exec into the container I can view the file contents and they are as expected.

That said, the file `debug-test.php` shows up in VSCode, but it's an empty file (i.e. it does not reflect the content in the container itself).

This wouldn't be a huge issue, but the files purpose is to test my setup of xdebug. It has a purposefully left in error that xdebug properly detects, but since the file is empty it doesn't show exactly where the error is in vscode; it just brings up the blank file and gives the proper error message without context.

Anyone know why this file is showing up as blank in mounted_folder?

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  wp:
    build: ../docker
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ../docker/debug-test.php:/var/www/html/debug-test.php:rw
      - ./mounted_folder:/var/www/html

    environment: 
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: true
    working_dir: /var/www/html

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: You're mounting the folder overtop of where you've mounted the file. You can try changing the order of the statements under `volumes:`, but I don't know if mounting inside of a mount is going to work as you expect either. The simple answer is to either put the `debug-test.php` into the folder you're mounting, or mount them to different locations.